# Hide Navigation Controller Search Bar & opened Large Title programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a `tableView`. I set the all settings about searchController ( Search Bar in Large Navigation Bar ) - ( open / close when scroll tableview ). I implemented `rightBarButtonItem` which name is 'Close' . I want to hide/close tableView and Search Bar with programmatically. I can hide tableView but not SearchBar.

When I do `isHidden` for `SearchBar` , The Large Navigation Bar doesnt shrink to normal size.

Pic 1. Opened search bar with scroll down.

[image]

Pic 2. Not Hidden Large Navigation Bar with programmatically ( searchar.isHidden not implemented here )

[image]

Thanks in advance.

I tried this before but not run

```
tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

Comment: at time to hide search controller you need to set prefer-large title of navigation bar is false

Comment: I dont use large title , also I tried that

Comment: navigation search bar or UIsearchBar what are you using . ?

Comment: UISearchController

Comment: @codeByThey Can you share a bit of your code ?

Answer (score 4):

I tried to find a proper way to hide search bar, but I didn't find. But I found a workaround to hide your search bar which is change content offset your table view.

You may try this function to hide your table view and search bar.

```
func hide() {
    tableView.isHidden = true
    let point = tableView.contentOffset
    let searchBarFrame = self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.frame
    let newPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y + searchBarFrame!.height)
    tableView.setContentOffset(newPoint, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just try this:**

```
 navigationItem.searchController = nil
```

**This is all my test code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

var isHidden = false

var searchController: UISearchController {

    let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    search.searchBar.placeholder = "hello world"

    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    return search
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "Test"

    tableView.delegate = self

    tableView.dataSource = self

    showSearchController()
}

@IBAction func isHiddenAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    isHidden = !isHidden

    self.tableView.isHidden = isHidden

    if isHidden {
        leftBarButtonItem.title = "Show"
        hiddenSearchController()

    } else {
        leftBarButtonItem.title = "Hidden"
        showSearchController()
    }
}

func hiddenSearchController() {
    navigationItem.searchController = nil
}

func showSearchController() {

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

[image: screenShots]

Comment: With this function searchbar is disappeared thats true but large navigation bar is not .

Comment: I dont use large title any time. If you can do with normal title , I want to accept your solution.

Comment: @codeByThey Please accept my answer if it helps you. And let people with the same problem find the right solution faster. Thank you!

Comment: It not works for me . I wll try with another soltion in 2 days and if it gives me a way to solution , again I open bounty and I wll give your points. Thanks