# iOS How to create Search Bar in a CollectionView Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

i already realized my `CollectionView` and i'm tying to create a `SearchBar` and a `TableView` in a `CollectionViewController`. I tried to put the `SearchBar` and the Table in the top of the `storyboard` but i can't put any of them. How can i realize them with the code? Do you have some idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689484/hide-navigation-controller-search-bar-opened-large-title-programmatically try the second answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your search bar goes together at your TableView. Just put the search bar a little up and the table a little more down and the won't be together.